# Imagemagick convert grayscale image to color

Tags: imagemagick

I created an image with `convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white white.png`, but it appears to have a greyscale color profile and this is undesirable.

`identify -verbose` shows

> Colorspace: Gray
> Type: Grayscale

for "normal" images, these properties don't even seem to be mentioned.

How can I change it so that the image can have color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force an RGB888 image like this:

```
convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white PNG24:white.png
```

Check:

```
identify -verbose white.png | egrep "Colorspace:|Type:"

Colorspace: sRGB
Type: Bilevel
```